# python syntax error "keyword can't be an expression"

Tags: python, syntax

I ran the following script and got the error message at the bottom.  I can't figure out why I am getting the error message.

```
def vp(ds_final_revised):
    df=ds_final_revised
    df = df.filter(df._type_ = 8)
    return df
```

error message:

```
Syntax Error.

File "vp", line 3
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Comment: `df._type_ = 8` isn't valid because `df._type_` is not a valid keyword name. I assume `df.filter()` has legitimate keyword arguments, but whatever you think you're doing, it's invalid.

Answer (score 0):

in line 3, `df = df.filter(df._type_ = 8)',  'df._type_ = 8` is invalid. Expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant:

```
df = df.filter(lambda x: x._type_ ==8)
```